# Why are morphisms in the usual category of metric spaces short maps rather than Lipshitz maps?

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory

In the usual category of metric spaces, morphisms are short maps (aka metric maps); that is, a morphism $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is a map satisfying $d_X(x,y)\leq d_Y(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x,y\in X$. This choice surprises me. Surely choosing morphisms to be Lipshitz maps (functions satisfying $d_X(x,y)\leq Bd_Y(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x,y\in X$ and fixed constant $B$) would give a more useful category since the short map condition seems so restrictive?

I am aware that short maps as morphisms is natural if one views metric spaces themselves as enriched categories (Lawvere metric spaces) and is interested in functors between Lawvere metric spaces. I am much more interested in knowing whether short maps perhaps ensure the category of metric spaces has better properties then Lipschitz maps? If so, how specifically?

Comment: One thing is that if you use Lipschitz maps then two metric spaces will be isomorphic if one is a 'scaled up' version of the other. This means that anything you define using a universal property (such as products for example) will only be defined up to scaling. So if the category of metric spaces and Lipschitz maps has products (I don't know if it does), they're not the usual product of metric spaces.

Comment: I don't know if the category of metric spaces and Lipschitz maps has nice properties or not (I'd be interested to know), but if it does you don't have to make an absolute choice between it and the category of metric spaces and short maps. Every short map is in particular a Lipschitz map, so there is a forgetful functor from one to the other, which lets you study how the categories relate to each other.

Comment: What would be your notion of an isomorphism in this category? Your definition would yield bilipschitz maps. But what if you want to get isometries? You would use short maps as your morphisms.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is that a bad thing though? I was under the impression that a lot of the time we are only interested in metric properties up to scaling (as long as one can control bounds on scaling), but I am far from an expert.

Comment: It depends on your objective. There are two different categories, if you prefer the Lipschitz one, there is nothing wrong with that. But you should accept that this is not the only choice, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

One reason to care is that the usual category of metric spaces and short maps (provided you allow two points to have infinite distance from one another) is very well behaved -- it's complete, cocomplete, and symmetric monoidal closed. See, for instance the introduction to Rosicky and Tholen's [*Approximate Injectivity*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05524.pdf). It's possible that the category of metric spaces with lipschitz maps doesn't enjoy these nice properties, and that's why people don't consider it as often. If we restrict attention to compact metric spaces with lipschitz maps, then we *definitely* don't enjoy these properties, since they're not closed under colimits (basically because of compactness) or limits (this I think would continue to be an issue even for the category of all metric spaces with lipschitz maps). See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91787/the-category-of-compact-metric-spaces) related question for more details.

Another reason is that the category of metric spaces with lipschitz maps "doesn't remember the metric" in the sense that two metric spaces with different metrics can still be isomorphic in this category (compare with two homeomorphic spaces equipped with different metrics). In this sense, the category "isn't actually seeing the metric structure", it's only seeing that part of the metric structure that we can detect via lipschitz functions (in much the same way that topological spaces only see the part of a metric we can detect via continuous functions)! This is closely related to @N.Virgo's comments about universal properties being only defined up to scaling. Of course, it's easy to see that the category of metric spaces and short maps doesn't have this issue -- it correctly "remembers" the metric structure in the sense that two isomorphic objects must have *exactly* the same metric.

Obviously this isn't a historically accurate picture, and I would love for someone with more experience with various categories of metric spaces to chime in!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I'm tempted to accept this as an answer but am hoping for more details on what categorical properties are lost when using lipschitz maps. For example, why do you suspect that it would still not be closed under limits when not restricting to compact metric spaces?

Answer (score 0):

In the other direction, the category of metric spaces (with real valued metrics) and Lipschitz maps has a nice property which is not shared by the category of metric spaces and short maps, namely, that it has (finite) coproducts.

Indeed, for two nonempty metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ with points $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ let $S$ be the disjoint (or *disjointified*) union and define $d_S$ so that the restrictions to $X$ and $Y$ are $d_X$ and $d_Y$, respectively, and $$d_S(x,y)=d_S(y,x)=d_X(x,x_0)+1+d(y_0,y)$$
for $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Together with the inclusions $i_X:X\to S$ and $i_Y:Y\to S$ (which are even short) we get a coproduct. For, if $f:X\to Z$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are Lipschitz with Lipschitz constants $L_f$ and $L_g$, the obvious map $h:S\to Z$ defined as $f$ on $X$ and as $g$ on $Y$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $$L_h\le \max\{L_f,L_g,d_Z(f(x_0),g(x_0))\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, within the context of metric spaces themselves, taking the morphisms between two metric spaces to be the maps which do not increase distances is the "correct" notion of morphism because it gives a natural class of morphisms within which isomorphic spaces are isometric. This seems like a reasonable desideratum in a category whose objects are metric spaces! It means, more informally, that in this category there is a notion of "scale", whereas that notion disappears if you allow Lipschitz morphisms.

The category of metric spaces and distance non-increasing maps also has good "homological" properties, every metric space $X$ has an injective envelope $\epsilon(X)$ and thus **Met** has "enough injectives". (It is even the case that $\epsilon(X)$ is compact if $X$ is compact, so the subcategory of compact metric spaces inherits this property.)

Also, to clarify a tension between the assertions in the previous answers, the category of metric spaces **Met** does not have coproducts, *i.e.* is not (even finitely) cocomplete. However, if one extends the notion of a metric to allow functions $d\colon X \times X \to [0,\infty]$ (*i.e.* allowing the distance function to take the value $\infty$ which is assumed to be obey $\infty \geq \infty+\infty\geq \infty$ *etc.*) then this category $\textbf{Met}_{\infty}$ (with the same notion of morphism as in **Met**) is complete and cocomplete.

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces then $X \bigsqcup Y$, the coproduct of $X$ and $Y$, is their disjoint union with metric $d$ where
$$
d(a,b) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} d_X(a,b),  & \text{ if } a,b \in X \\ d_Y(a,b), & \text{if } a,b \in Y\\
\infty & \text{ otherwise}.\end{array}\right.
$$